# MySQL - Wrong value

Tags: mysql, sql

I try calculate some numbers and i sweared alltime because it failing and then i tryed this:

```
SELECT SUM( 10 *1 ) 
FROM user_achievements
INNER JOIN achievements
WHERE user_achievements.user_id =8
```

and it says its: 420 ?!?

I try make this working:

```
SELECT SUM((SELECT score_base FROM achievements WHERE id = user_achievements.achievement_id)*((SELECT pixels_multiplier FROM achievements WHERE id = user_achievements.achievement_id)) * achievement_level) * achievement_level FROM user_achievements INNER JOIN achievements WHERE user_achievements.user_id=2
```

achievements:
id,
levels,
pixels_base,
score_base,
pixels_multiplier

user_achievements:
user_id,
achievement_id,
achievement_level

Comment: Can you show the create statements for the two tables. You can leave out any fields not used.

Comment: Added! Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query is return 420, that means that 42 rows are returned in the result set before the aggregation.

This is your query:

```
SELECT sum(10*1)
FROM user_achievements ua cross join
     achievements a
WHERE ua.user_id = 8;
```

If I had to guess, you are missing a join:

```
SELECT sum(10*1)
FROM user_achievements ua join
     achievements a
     on ua.achievement_id = a.id
WHERE ua.user_id = 8;
```

EDIT:

This is the query in the comment:

```
SELECT sum((SELECT score_base
            FROM achievements
            WHERE id = ua.achievement_id
            ) *
            (SELECT pixels_multiplier
             FROM achievements
             WHERE id = ua.achievement_id
            )
           )
FROM user_achievements ua join
     achievements a
     on ua.achievement_id = a.id
WHERE ua.user_id = 2;
```

It shouldn't even parse.  Subqueries are not allowed in aggregations.  Try this:

```
SELECT sum(a.score_base * a.pixels_multiplier)
FROM user_achievements ua join
     achievements a
     on ua.achievement_id = a.id
WHERE ua.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'a.achievement_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Just change the a to ua and the ua to a in that comparison

Comment: @user3249998 . . . I don't know the names of the fields in your table.  I was showing an example of what the query would look like.  Use it as a guide given your own database.

Comment: I tryed this and not working: SELECT sum((SELECT score_base FROM achievements WHERE id = user_achievements.achievement_id) *(SELECT pixels_multiplier FROM achievements WHERE id = user_achievements.achievement_id))
FROM user_achievements user_achievements join
     achievements a
     on user_achievements.achievement_id = a.id
WHERE user_achievements.user_id = 2;

Comment: Both give this error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'user_achievements.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Ok it fails little bit :/ I runned this query: SELECT sum((SELECT score_base
            FROM achievements
            WHERE id = ua.achievement_id
            ) *
            (SELECT pixels_multiplier
             FROM achievements
             WHERE id = ua.achievement_id
            ) *
   (SELECT achievement_level FROM user_achievements WHERE user_id = 2 AND achievement_id = ua.achievement_id)
           )
FROM user_achievements ua join
     achievements a
     on ua.achievement_id = a.id
WHERE ua.user_id = 2;

And it returns: 430 but its 1750

Comment: Try the query in the answer.